# Choose closest x elements by index in a list/vector

Tags: r, vector, indices, closest

If I have a vector such as `x <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`, I want a function f such that 
`f(vector,index,num)` where it takes the vector and gives me `num` "closest" elements to that one on the index
Examples:
`f(x,3,4) = c(1,2,4,5)`
`f(x,1,5) = c(2,3,4,5,6)
f(x,8,3) = c(6,7,9)`

Since there is also the issue where if we have an odd num, we will need to choose whether to pick left or right side by symmetry, let's go with choosing the left side (but right side is ok too)
i.e `f(x,4,5) = c(1,2,3,5,6) and f(x,7,3) = c(5,6,8)`

I hope my question is clear, thank you for any help/responses!

edit: The original vector of `c(1:9)` is arbitrary, the vector could be a vector of strings, or a vector of length 1000 with shuffled numbers with repeats etc.

i.e `c(1,7,4,2,3,7,2,6,234,56,8)`

Comment: Can you tell us more about your application? If x is always a contiguous integer range like your example `1:9`, we can come up with a closed-form solution. Can we assume the vector is in order? no duplicates? I don't see the point in coding up a recursive search if we can find a simple closed-form.

Comment: Hi there - my bad, the vector could be a bunch of strings such as `c("a","b","c")` and any order! I only chose 1:9 out of simplicity

Comment: Please don't choose an easy example like 1:9, can you give a harder example? Oh when you mean "closest", you only mean "closest by index", you don't want us to compare element values

Comment: That's right! Sorry I should have chosen a different vector, i'll edit the original question to reflect this

Comment: Look, if `num` is even, there is always a closed-form solution: `index - num/2 ... index + num/2`, unless index is near the start/end of the vector. And if `num` is odd, you need to tell us how to break ties.

Comment: Hi there
Sorry if my original question was unclear, but i wrote that to break ties or to deal with odd value num's we choose the "left side" or the lower index as preference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num_closest_by_indices <- function(v, idx, num) {
  # Try the base case, where idx is not within (num/2) of the edge
  i <- abs(seq_along(x) - idx)
  i[idx] <- +Inf # sentinel

  # If there are not enough elements in the base case, incrementally add more
  for (cutoff_idx in seq(floor(num/2), num)) {
    if (sum(i <= cutoff_idx) >= num) {
      # This will add two extra indices every iteration. Strictly if we have an even length, we should add the leftmost one first and `continue`, to break ties towards the left.
      return(v[i <= cutoff_idx])
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an illustration of this algorithm: we rank the indices in order of desirability, then pick the lowest `num` legal ones:

```
> seq_along(x)
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> seq_along(x) - idx
  -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
> i <- abs(seq_along(x) - idx)
   2  1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
> i[idx] <- +Inf # sentinel to prevent us returning the element itself
   2   1 Inf   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Now we can just find `num` elements with smallest values (break ties arbitrarily, unless you have a preference (left)).
Our first guess is all indices <= (num/2) ; this might not be enough if `index` is within `(num/2)` of the start/end.

```
> i <= 2
  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> v[i <= 2]
  1 2 4 5
```

So, adapting @dash2's code to handle the corner cases where some indices are illegal (nonpositive, or > length(x)), i.e. `! %in% 1:L`. Then `min(elems)` would be the number of illegal indices which we cannot pick, hence we must pick `abs(min(elems))` more.

Notes:

- in the end the code is simpler and faster to handle it by three piecewise cases. Aww.
- it actually seems to simplify things if we pick `(num+1)` indices, then remove `idx` before returning the answer. Using `result[-idx]` to remove it.

Comment: Wow thanks for all the answers guys! It looks like this problem is trickier than i first imagined (probably why i struggled a bit with it haha) but the solutions look good :)

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
f <- function (vec, elem, n) {
  elems <- seq(elem - ceiling(n/2), elem + floor(n/2))
  if (max(elems) > length(vec)) elems <- elems - (max(elems) - length(vec))
  if (elems[1] < 1) elems <- elems + (1 - elems[1])
  elems <- setdiff(elems, elem)
  vec[elems]
}
```

Giving results:

```
> f(1:9, 1, 5)
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
> f(1:9, 9, 5)
[1] 4 5 6 7 8
> f(1:9, 2, 5)
[1] 1 3 4 5 6
> f(1:9, 4, 5)
[1] 1 2 3 5 6
> f(1:9, 4, 4)
[1] 2 3 5 6
> f(1:9, 2, 4)
[1] 1 3 4 5
> f(1:9, 1, 4)
[1] 2 3 4 5
> f(1:9, 9, 4)
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: At the edge cases, some of those indices will be illegal (negative, or > length). So you have to choose `num` of the legal indices. Either by iteration or special-casing.

Comment: Edited. I thought the orig poster was happy to throw an error in this case, didn't notice `f(1:9, 1, 5)`.

Comment: Three piecewise cases, then.

Answer (score 0):

Start a function with the variable argument `x` first, and the reference `table` and `n` after

```
.nearest_n <- function(x, table, n) {
```

The algorithm assumes that `table` is numeric, without any duplicates, and all values finite; `n` has to be less than or equal to the length of the table

```
    ## assert & setup
    stopifnot(
        is.numeric(table), !anyDuplicated(table), all(is.finite(table)),
        n <= length(table)
    )
```

Sort the table and then 'clamp' maximum and minimum values

```
    ## sort and clamp
    table <- c(-Inf, sort(table), Inf)
    len <- length(table)
```

Find the interval in `table` where `x` occurs; `findInterval()` uses an efficient search. Use the interval index as the initial lower index, and add 1 for the upper index, making sure to stay in-bounds.

```
    ## where to start?
    lower <- findInterval(x, table)
    upper <- min(lower + 1L, len)
```

Find the nearest `n` neighbors by comparing the lower and upper index distance to `x`, record the nearest value, and increment the lower or upper index as appropriate and making sure to stay in-bounds

```
    ## find
    nearest <- numeric(n)
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        if (abs(x - table[lower]) < abs(x - table[upper])) {
            nearest[i] = table[lower]
            lower = max(1L, lower - 1L)
        } else {
            nearest[i] = table[upper]
            upper = min(len, upper + 1L)
        }
    }
```

Then return the solution and finish the function

```
    nearest
}
```

The code might seem verbose, but is actually relatively efficient because the only operations on the entire vector (`sort()`, `findInterval()`) are implemented efficiently in R.

A particular advantage of this approach is that it can be vectorized in it's first argument, calculating the test for using lower (`use_lower = ...`) as a vector and using `pmin()` / `pmax()` as clamps.

```
.nearest_n <- function(x, table, n) {
    ## assert & setup
    stopifnot(
        is.numeric(table), !anyDuplicated(table), all(is.finite(table)),
        n <= length(table)
    )

    ## sort and clamp
    table <- c(-Inf, sort(table), Inf)
    len <- length(table)

    ## where to start?
    lower <- findInterval(x, table)
    upper <- pmin(lower + 1L, len)

    ## find
    nearest <- matrix(0, nrow = length(x), ncol = n)
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        use_lower <- abs(x - table[lower]) < abs(x - table[upper])
        nearest[,i] <- ifelse(use_lower, table[lower], table[upper])
        lower[use_lower] <- pmax(1L, lower[use_lower] - 1L)
        upper[!use_lower] <- pmin(len, upper[!use_lower] + 1L)
    }

    # return
    nearest
}
```

For instance

```
> set.seed(123)
> table <- sample(100, 10)
> sort(table)
 [1]  5 29 41 42 50 51 79 83 86 91
> .nearest_n(c(30, 20), table, 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   29   41   42   50
[2,]   29    5   41   42
```

Generalize this by taking any argument and coercing it to the required form using a reference look-up table `table0` and the indexes into it `table1`

```
nearest_n <- function(x, table, n) {
    ## coerce to common form
    table0 <- sort(unique(c(x, table)))
    x <- match(x, table0)
    table1 <- match(table, table0)

    ## find nearest
    m <- .nearest_n(x, table1, n)

    ## result in original form
    matrix(table0[m], nrow = nrow(m))
}
```

As an example...

```
> set.seed(123)
> table <- sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 30)
> nearest_n(c("M", "Z"), table, 5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "o"  "L"  "O"  "l"  "P" 
[2,] "Z"  "z"  "Y"  "y"  "w"
```